# Error launching application on simulator (flutter)

Tags: xcode, flutter, dependencies, cocoapods, podfile

```
10 errors generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FBSDKCoreKit' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FBSDKLoginKit' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.